# Can't upgrade MySQL in Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

At this moment (April 6, 2023), I can't upgrade MySQL (from 8.0.30) to 8.0.31 or 8.0.32 in Google Cloud SQL in the region `europe-west1`. But I see in the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/release-notes) of Cloud SQL that 8.0.31 and 8.0.32 are already available for minor version upgrade:

[image]

I don't see the 8.0.31 and 8.0.32 in upgrade dropdown:
[image]

Also, I received error message in CLI when I tried to reference those version - MYSQL_8_0_31 from this [source](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/SqlDatabaseVersion):

```
gcloud sql instances patch my-db-clone --project test-project --database-version=MYSQL_8_0_31
```

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.patch) HTTPError 400: Invalid request: Database Type update not allowed: Cannot update from [MYSQLD_8_0_30] to [MYSQLD_8_0_31].
```

Comment: Thanks @RoarS. I have tried it right now. And, also, I received an error: `(gcloud.sql.instances.patch) HTTPError 400: Invalid request: Unknown maintenance version format: MYSQL_8_0_31.`

Comment: I have tried this method too. My current available version is MySQL 8.0.30

Comment: I don't see the field `availableMaintenanceVersions` . But I see only this field: `maintenanceVersion: MYSQL_8_0_30.R20230314.03_02`

Comment: Then you are at latest maintenance version for your instance, and `--maintenance-version=MAINTENANCE_VERSION` is a dead-end. I'll remove my above. comments. Tried to add a MySQL-instance, and 8.0.32 shows up in that list.

Comment: @RoarS. Which region do you use for MySQL instance 8.0.32?

Comment: europe-north1 (Finland)

Comment: When I am adding a new instance of MySQL, I also see MySQL 8.0.32 in list of available versions. But I can't upgrade my current version MySQL 8.0.30 to 8.0.32. Maybe I need wait sometime because today I have updated MySQL 8.0.18 to 8.0.30. I mean maybe Cloud SQL can't immediately migrate from 8.0.18 to 8.0.32.

Answer (score 1):

Google Support Agent here,

I also reproduced the same issue while upgrading to `MYSQL_8_0_31`. I couldn’t find `MYSQL_8_0_31` in the console and with the command line I’m getting the same error.

After some investigation I found that, When upgrading to the  `MySQL v8.0.31` version, a crash has been confirmed if it is not a clean shutdown, so it is temporarily blocked `MySQL` instances from upgrading to `8.0.31` and above.

ETA for lifting the restrictions to upgrade to `8.0.31` is early/mid April as of now. You may contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) to confirm this.

So the workaround would be to upgrade/keep to version 8.0.30 until version 8.0.31 is available for upgrade.